# Unix one-liner to swap/transpose two lines in multiple text files?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, text-files

I wish to swap or transpose pairs of lines according to their line-numbers (e.g., switching the positions of lines 10 and 15) in multiple text files using a UNIX tool such as sed or awk.

For example, I believe this sed command should swap lines 14 and 26 in a single file:

```
sed -n '14p' infile_name > outfile_name
sed -n '26p' infile_name >> outfile_name
```

How can this be extended to work on multiple files? Any one-liner solutions welcome.

Comment: To do this in-place in one step is going to require storing the contents of the first line and storing the contents of every subsequent line until the target line and then printing the target line, the intermediate lines and then the original line and then just printing the rest of the contents of the file. (Also, no, those two sed commands will not swap those two lines. They will simply print the first line and then the second line to `outfile_name` and do nothing to `infile_name` and `outfile_name` will only contain those two lines.) `awk` can do what you want; using `sed` will be harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '10,15!b;10h;10!H;15!d;x;s/^([^\n]*)(.*\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/' f1 f2 fn
```

This stores a range of lines in the hold space and then swaps the first and last lines following the completion of the range.

The `i` flag edits each file (`f1`,`f2` ... `fn`) in place.

Comment: Almost perfect—but what if I wanted to swap lines 1 and 2? It doesn't seem to work in that case.

Comment: Oops left a newline in by mistake. Edited the solution so will work for consecutive line.

Comment: @mklement0 the `i` flag by default also invokes the `s` flag which treats each new file as a separate file and any addresses are unique to each file. So this does work for  multiple files as is.

Comment: Well done, I voted it up yesterday, but I didn't have time to comment - the only thing you could use more of is explanation. It would be useful to hear you mention a bit more of the logic.

Comment: e.g. first operate on only the transpose space `10,15!b` means branch over the rest of the logic if its not lines 10-15, a hold space pattern  window is built up over the transpose line range,  the lines between the transpose range are deleted and not printed, when the last line of the transpose range is reached the line is printed (since it will be the new first line), then the hold space is swapped `x` into the pattern space and then a substitution `s` swaps the first and last lines of the saved transpose space by regex using newlines.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying `-i`'s line-numbering behavior. As an aside: OSX, as of 10.10, comes with an _older_ BSD `sed` version that does _not_ do per-file line numbering with `-i`, but more recent BSD `sed` versions _do_ (e.g., on FreeBSD 10, where the _old_ `-i` behavior is now provided by `-I`). It `is` possible to make your command work with BSD `sed` as well, but the inability to use `[^\n]` there (`\n` is not supported inside a character class) makes it quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to edit a file, you can use `ed`, the standard editor. Your task is rather easy in `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' 14m26 26-m14- w q | ed -s file
```

How does it work?

- `14m26` tells `ed` to take line #14 and move it after line #26
- `26-m14-` tells `ed` to take the line before line #26 (which is your original line #26) and move it after line preceding line #14 (which is where your line #14 originally was)
- `w` tells `ed` to write the file
- `q` tells `ed` to quit.

If your numbers are in a variable, you can do:

```
linea=14
lineb=26
{
    printf '%dm%d\n' "$linea" "$lineb"
    printf '%d-m%d-\n' "$lineb" "$linea"
    printf '%s\n' w q
} | ed -s file
```

or something similar. Make sure that `linea<lineb`.

Comment: Great stuff; `ed` doesn't get enough love. [ed is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) and seems to be present on _most_ platforms, but I've noticed that it's not preinstalled on Debian. Similarly, Windows users running Cygwin or MSYS are out of luck. Does anybody know of other Unix-like platforms where it's not preinstalled?

Comment: Hi mklement0. I just installed a fresh Debian 8.0 and indeed, `ed` isn't installed by default...

Comment: Thanks for checking. It is curious and unfortunate, because `ed` can be quite handy in general (as you've demonstrated here), but especially in situations where you truly want to the edit the _existing_ file (as opposed to _replacing_ it with a newly created file of the same name, which can destroy symlinks). A follow-up on what I said about Cygwin and MSYS on Windows: `ed` _is_ offered, but only as an _option_ (Editors package), whereas MSYS doesn't offer it at all.
I also hear that on some platforms (don't know which) `ed` is a symlink to another editor, such as `vim`.

Comment: Beautiful answer, I new there out should be a utility like this.

Answer (score 6):

- If you want ***robust* in-place updating** of your input files, use **[gniourf_gniourf's excellent `ed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868180/45375)**
- If you have ***GNU* `sed`** and want to **in-place updating with *multiple* files at once**, use
  **[@potong's excellent GNU `sed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858758/45375)** (see below for a portable alternative, and the bottom for an explanation)

Note: **`ed` truly updates the *existing* file**, **whereas `sed`'s `-i` option creates a temporary file behind the scenes, which then *replaces* the original** - while typically not an issue, this **can have undesired side effects**, most notably, replacing a symlink with a regular file (by contrast, file permissions are correctly preserved).

Below are **POSIX-compliant shell functions** that **wrap both answers**.

---

**Stdin/stdout processing**, based on [@potong's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858758/45375):

- [POSIX `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) doesn't support `-i` for in-place updating.
- It also doesn't support using `\n` inside a character class, so `[^\n]` must be replaced with a cumbersome workaround that *positively* defines all character except `\n` that can occur on a line - this is a achieved with a character class combining printable characters with all (ASCII) control characters other than `\n` included as literals (via a command substitution using `printf`).
- Also note the need to split the `sed` script into two `-e` options, because POSIX `sed` requires that a branching command (`b`, in this case) be terminated with either an actual newline or continuation in a separate `-e` option.

```sh
# SYNOPSIS
#   swapLines lineNum1 lineNum2
swapLines() {
  [ "$1" -ge 1 ] || { printf "ARGUMENT ERROR: Line numbers must be decimal integers >= 1.\n" >&2; return 2; }
  [ "$1" -le "$2" ] || { printf "ARGUMENT ERROR: The first line number ($1) must be <= the second ($2).\n" >&2; return 2; }
  sed -e "$1"','"$2"'!b' -e ''"$1"'h;'"$1"'!H;'"$2"'!d;x;s/^\([[:print:]'"$(printf '\001\002\003\004\005\006\007\010\011\013\014\015\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\177')"']*\)\(.*\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/'
}
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n' | swapLines 1 3 
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

---

**In-place updating**, based on [gniourf_gniourf's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868180/45375):

Small caveats:

- While [`ed` is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), it doesn't come preinstalled on *all* platforms, notably not on Debian and the Cygwin and MSYS Unix-emulation environments for Windows.
- `ed` always reads the input file *as a whole* into memory.

```sh
# SYNOPSIS
#   swapFileLines lineNum1 lineNum2 file
swapFileLines() {
  [ "$1" -ge 1 ] || { printf "ARGUMENT ERROR: Line numbers must be decimal integers >= 1.\n" >&2; return 2; }
  [ "$1" -le "$2" ] || { printf "ARGUMENT ERROR: The first line number ($1) must be <= the second ($2).\n" >&2; return 2; }
  ed -s "$3" <<EOF
H
$1m$2
$2-m$1-
w
EOF
}
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n' > file
$ swapFileLines 1 3 file
$ cat file
line 3
line 2
line 1
```

---

An **explanation of [@potong's  GNU `sed`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858758/45375)**:

His command swaps lines 10 and 15:

```
sed -ri '10,15!b;10h;10!H;15!d;x;s/^([^\n]*)(.*\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/' f1 f2 fn
```

- `-r` activates support for *extended* regular expressions; here, notably, it allows use of *unescaped* parentheses to form *capture groups*.
- `-i` specifies that the files specified as operands (`f1`, `f2`, `fn`) be updated *in place*, *without backup*, since *no* optional suffix for a backup file is adjoined to the `-i` option.
- `10,15!b` means that all lines that do *not* (`!`) fall into the range of lines `10` through `15` should branch (`b`) implicitly to the *end of the script* (given that no target-label name follows `b`), which means that the following commands are *skipped* for these lines. Effectively, they are simply *printed as is*.
- `10h` copies (`h`) line number `10` (the start of the range) to the so-called *hold space*, which is an auxiliary buffer.
- `10!H` *appends* (`H`) every line that is *not* line `10` - which in this case implies lines `11` through `15` - to the hold space.
- `15!d` *deletes* (`d`) every line that is *not* line `15` (here, lines `10` through `14`) and branches to the end of the script (skips remaining commands). By *deleting* these lines, they are *not* printed.
- `x`, which is executed only for line `15` (the end of the range), replaces the so-called *pattern space* with the contents of the hold space, which at that point holds all lines in the range (`10` through `15`); the pattern space is the buffer on which `sed` commands operate, and whose contents are printed by default (unless `-n` was specified).
- `s/^([^\n]*)(.*\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/` then uses capture groups (parenthesized subexpressions of the regular expression that forms the first argument passed to function `s`) to partition the contents of the pattern space into the 1st line (`^([^\n]*)`), the middle lines (`(.*\n)`), and the last line (`(.*)`), and then, in the replacement string (the second argument passed to function `s`), uses *backreferences* to place the last line (`\3`) before the middle lines (`\2`), followed by the first line (`\1`), effectively swapping the first and last lines in the range. Finally, the modified pattern space is printed.

As you can see, only the *range* of lines spanning the two lines to swap is held in memory, whereas all other lines are passed through individually, which makes this approach memory-efficient.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {if(FNR==14) x=$0;if(FNR==26) y=$0;next} 
FNR==14 {$0=y} FNR==26 {$0=x} {print}
' file file > file_with_swap
```

Comment: Nice - easier to understand than @potong's `sed` command, but it comes at the cost of having to read the file _twice_; you could easily generalize this by passing the line numbers as variables (e.g,  `-v l1=14 -v l2=26`). You're actually not using any features that are specific to GNU `awk`, so this should work with _any_ POSIX-compatible `awk` implementation.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, I wasn't sure if all the common AWKs could do it. But I actually prefer gniourf_gniourf's nice *ed* solution!

Comment: Agreed - it is the only true _file_-editing solution, it is efficient, and conceptually clearer than the accepted answer. The accepted answer has 2 advantages, though: it can process multiple files at once, and it's more memory-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the following helper script allows using the power of `find ... -exec ./script '{}' l1 l2 \;` to locate the target files and to swap lines `l1` & `l2` in each file in place. (it requires that there are no **identical duplicate** lines within the file that fall within the search range) The script uses `sed` to read the two swap lines from each file into an indexed array and passes the lines to `sed` to complete the swap by matching. The `sed` call uses its **"matched  first  address"  state** to limit the second expression swap to the first occurrence. An example use of the helper script below to swap lines `5` & `15` in all matching files is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "lnum*" -exec ../swaplines.sh '{}' 5 15 \;
```

For example, the `find` call above found files `lnumorig.txt` and `lnumfile.txt` in the present directory originally containing:

```
$ head -n20 lnumfile.txt.bak
 1  A simple line of test in a text file.
 2  A simple line of test in a text file.
 3  A simple line of test in a text file.
 4  A simple line of test in a text file.
 5  A simple line of test in a text file.
 6  A simple line of test in a text file.
<snip>
14  A simple line of test in a text file.
15  A simple line of test in a text file.
16  A simple line of test in a text file.
17  A simple line of test in a text file.
18  A simple line of test in a text file.
19  A simple line of test in a text file.
20  A simple line of test in a text file.
```

And swapped the lines `5` & `15` as intended:

```
$ head -n20 lnumfile.txt
 1  A simple line of test in a text file.
 2  A simple line of test in a text file.
 3  A simple line of test in a text file.
 4  A simple line of test in a text file.
15  A simple line of test in a text file.
 6  A simple line of test in a text file.
<snip>
14  A simple line of test in a text file.
 5  A simple line of test in a text file.
16  A simple line of test in a text file.
17  A simple line of test in a text file.
18  A simple line of test in a text file.
19  A simple line of test in a text file.
20  A simple line of test in a text file.
```

The helper script itself is:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 ] && {              # validate requierd input (defaults set below)
    printf "error: insufficient input calling '%s'. usage: file [line1 line2]\n" "${0//*\//}" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

l1=${2:-10}                 # default/initialize line numbers to swap
l2=${3:-15}

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do  # read lines to swap into indexed array
    a+=( "$line" ); 
done <<<"$(sed -n $((l1))p "$1" && sed -n $((l2))p "$1")"

((${#a[@]} < 2)) && {       # validate 2 lines read
    printf "error: requested lines '%d & %d' not found in file '%s'\n" $l1 $l2 "$1"
    exit 1
}

                            # swap lines in place with sed (remove .bak for no backups)
sed -i.bak -e "s/${a[1]}/${a[0]}/" -e "0,/${a[0]}/s/${a[0]}/${a[1]}/" "$1"

exit 0
```

Even though I didn't manage to get it all done in a **one-liner** I decided it was worth posting in case you can make some use of it or take ideas from it. **Note:** if you do make use of it, test to your satisfaction before turning it loose on your system. The script currently uses `sed -i.bak ...` to create backups of the files changed for testing purposes. You can remove the `.bak` when you are satisfied it meets your needs.

If you have no use for setting default lines to swap in the helper script itself, then I would change the first validation check to `[ -z $1 -o -z $2 -o $3 ]` to insure **all** required arguments are given when the script is called.

While it does **identify the lines to be swapped by number**, it **relies on the direct match of each line** to accomplish the swap. This means that any **identical duplicate** lines up to the end of the swap range will cause an unintended match and failue to swap the intended lines. This is part of the limitation imposed by not storing each line within the range of lines to be swapped as discussed in the comments. It's a tradeoff. There are many, many ways to approach this, all will have their benefits and drawbacks. Let me know if you have any questions.

---

### Brute Force Method

Per your comment, I revised the helper script to use the brute forth copy/swap method that would eliminate the problem of any duplicate lines in the search range. This helper obtains the lines via `sed` as in the original, but then reads all lines from `file` to `tmpfile` swapping the appropriately numbered lines when encountered. After the `tmpfile` is filled, it is copied to the original `file` and `tmpfile` is removed.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 ] && {              # validate requierd input (defaults set below)
    printf "error: insufficient input calling '%s'. usage: file [line1 line2]\n" "${0//*\//}" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

l1=${2:-10}                 # default/initialize line numbers to swap
l2=${3:-15}

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do  # read lines to swap into indexed array
    a+=( "$line" ); 
done <<<"$(sed -n $((l1))p "$1" && sed -n $((l2))p "$1")"

((${#a[@]} < 2)) && {       # validate 2 lines read
    printf "error: requested lines '%d & %d' not found in file '%s'\n" $l1 $l2 "$1"
    exit 1
}

                            # create tmpfile, set trap, truncate
fn="$1"
rmtemp () { cp "$tmpfn" "$fn"; rm -f "$tmpfn"; }
trap rmtemp SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT

declare -i n=1
tmpfn="$(mktemp swap_XXX)"
:> "$tmpfn"

                            # swap lines in place with a tmpfile
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do

    if ((n == l1)); then
        printf "%s\n" "${a[1]}" >> "$tmpfn"
    elif ((n == l2)); then
        printf "%s\n" "${a[0]}" >> "$tmpfn"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$tmpfn"
    fi
    ((n++))

done < "$fn"

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but my files often contain identical duplicate lines, so pattern matching isn't really an option.

Comment: Win some, you lose some. I was testing on source code, so it worked remarkably well, but it was apparent that any identical duplicates would cause immediate failure. The other approach that I thought of, was a simple 'brute force' approach. Read both lines to swap with `sed` (as above), then read/copy the file line-by-line into a `tmpfile` swapping `line1->2` and `line2->1` as they are encountered during the read (then `cp tmpfile origfile && rm tmpfile`). That could also work with identical duplicates.

Comment: @Roger I rewrote the helper script to use the **brute force** method instead of the replacement with `sed` matching. It will swap based on line numbers only. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

if, you want swap two lines, to create script "swap.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -n "1,$((${2}-1))p" "$1"
sed -n "${3}p" "$1"
sed -n "$((${2}+1)),$((${3}-1))p" "$1"
sed -n "${2}p" "$1"
sed -n "$((${3}+1)),\$p" "$1"
```

next

```
sh swap.sh infile_name 14 26 > outfile_name
```

Comment: Does this work on multiple files, though? Say, *.txt?

Comment: @Roger I do not understand what you mean ..... `for f in $(ls *.txt) ; do sh swap.sh $f 14 26 > ${f}.swap; done` ..... this is what you need?

Comment: Packaging the functionality as a script is commendable (though invoking sed that many times is inefficient), but _your script needs conditionals to also work with edge cases_, such as the first line number being `1` (you need to add `[ "$2" -gt 1 ] && ` before the 1st command), and the line numbers being adjacent numbers, such as `14` and `15` (you need to add `[ "$((${2}+1 <= ${3}-1))" -eq 1 ] && `before the 3rd command).

Comment: @mklement0 thanks a lot for your comments , I have been studying the responses to learn ..... I fixed the most relevant ..... but conditionals do not add them as there are better answer than mine and thought delete in future ..... thanks, again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree that there are better answers, so deleting yours is certainly an option, but - given that it shows some interesting shell techniques - another option is to (a) add the conditionals and (b) state the limitations (inefficiency), and, optionally, (c) point to the better answers.

Comment: One final thought: re `for f in $(ls *.txt); do`: it is both more efficient and, more importantly, more _robust_ to simply use `for f in *.txt; do` (doesn't break with filenames with embedded spaces).

Comment: @mklement0 :-o I did not know that .... I always used the other way .... again thanks appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 0):

If the line numbers to be swapped are fixed then you might want to try something like the `sed` command in the following example to have lines swapped in multiple files in-place:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# prep test files
for f in a b c ; do
    ( for i in {1..30} ; do echo $f$i ; done ) > /tmp/$f
done

sed -i -s -e '14 {h;d}' -e '15 {N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;G;x;d}' -e '26 G' /tmp/{a,b,c}
# -i: inplace editing
# -s: treat each input file separately
# 14 {h;d} # first swap line: hold ; suppress
# 15 {N;N;...;G;x;d} # lines between: collect, append held line; hold result; suppress
# 26 G # second swap line: append held lines (and output them all)

# dump test files
cat /tmp/{a,b,c}
```

(This is according to Etan Reisner's comment.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap two lines, you can send it through twice, you could make it loop in one `sed` script if you really wanted, but this works:

e.g.

test.txt: `for a in {1..10}; do echo "this is line $a"; done >> test.txt`

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
this is line 6
this is line 7
this is line 8
this is line 9
this is line 10
```

Then to swap lines `6` and `9`:

`sed ':a;6,8{6h;6!H;d;ba};9{p;x};' test.txt | sed '7{h;d};9{p;x}'`

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
this is line 9
this is line 7
this is line 8
this is line 6
this is line 10
```

In the first `sed` it builds up the hold space with lines 6 through 8. 
At line 9 it prints line 9 then prints the hold space (lines 6 through 8) this accomplishes the first move of 9 to place 6. Note: `6h; 6!H` avoids a new line at the top of the pattern space.

The second move occurs in the second `sed` script it saves line 7 to the hold space, then deletes it and prints it after line 9.

To make it quasi-generic you can use variables like this: 
`A=3 && B=7 && sed ':a;'${A}','$((${B}-1))'{'${A}'h;'${A}'!H;d;ba};'${B}'{p;x};' test.txt | sed $(($A+1))'{h;d};'${B}'{p;x}'`

Where `A` and `B` are the lines you want to swap, in this case lines 3 and 7.