# how swap lines with awk with only a single pass and limited memory use?

Tags: awk, swap, gawk

in a previous post, this answer was shown: [answer user2138595](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874375/4767343), though beautiful , the problem is that you should read the input file twice.

I wish to make a GNU awk script to read input only once.

```
cat swap_line.awk
```

you get

```
BEGIN {
  if(init > end){
    exit 1;
  }
  flag = 1;
  memory_init = "";
  memory = ""
}
{
  if (NR != init && NR != end){
    if(flag==1){
      print $0;
    }else{
      memory = memory""$0"\n";
    }
  }else if(end == init){
    print $0;
  }else if(NR == init){
    flag = 0;
    memory_init = $0;
  }else{
    #NR == end
    print $0;
    printf("%s",memory);
    print memory_init;
    flag = 1;
  }
}
END {
  #if end is greater than the number of lines of the file
  if(flag == 0){
    printf("%s",memory);
    print memory_init;
  }
}
```

The scripts works well

```
cat input
1
2
3
4
5

awk -v init=2 -v end=4 -f swap_line.awk input
1
4
3
2
5

awk -v init=2 -v end=2 -f swap_line.awk input
1
2
3
4
5

awk -v init=2 -v end=8 -f swap_line.awk input 
1
3
4
5
2
```

**QUESTION**

how could i make a script in a better way ? because, I do not like to use the `memory` variable, since for large files can have problems, for example if the input file is 10 million lines and want to do a swap between line 1 and line 10 million, I store 9,999,998 lines in `memory` variable

Comment: Why is this tagged bash, if you'll only accept a solution written in awk? (If you would accept a solution in pure bash, with no awk, then perhaps the title needs to be changed).

Comment: That said -- unless you can guarantee that the two lines are the same length (or, with significantly more algorithmic complexity, guarantee that the line later in the original file is shorter than the one coming from towards its beginning), what you're asking is literally impossible without *some* kind of external storage. That could just be as simple as writing a temporary file to disk, or writing the output to a different file from the input, but somewhere the content needs to be stored. A solution can certainly use disk rather than memory, however.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy done, remove tag bash, thank you

Comment: Right, then. I could have written a pure-bash answer, but there are other folks here who know awk far better than I do; I'll leave this to them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if it is impossible: without using memory , I would like to see a better solution to learn from it

Comment: I don't see how you can do better than storing the intermediate lines in memory with `awk` since it can't seek around the file which I would think is necessary for any solution that doesn't involve buffering in memory.

Comment: This might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you are interested in general awk/idiomatic improvements.

Comment: The only improvement I can see is starting the if/elseif tree with the `end==init`condition, as in this case nothing is necessary to do and it avoid the other tests, order sounds ok for the remaining test.

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...well, "can't" is a bit strong. Natively, sure, but one can seek around using `dd`, for instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But that presupposes that we know where to seek to with `dd` though and that seems to go counter to the question. We could make guesses I suppose which could limit what we need to store in memory though.

Comment: @EtanReisner, indeed. I was thinking something along the lines of natively copying until we hit the first line, storing the offset-in-bytes at that point, reading and updating offsets until we find out where in bytes the second line begins and ends, and then using dd to copy everything else. Which still isn't one-pass, because truly one-pass isn't possible here without using memory, but it's a bit closer.

Comment: I think there is consensus that it is impossible without using memory , reading the file once using awk . I'll leave the question one day and delete , I must rethink my problem better .... thanks very much

Comment: Ah, that's not the direction I was thinking about with `dd` but that could work.

Comment: It could be done it *1.5 passes*. Having that `b>a` you could print all lines until `a`. Save all lines from `a` to `b` in buffer. When `b` is reached, exchange the lines `a` and `b` in buffer, step back to position `a` print the buffer and then go on print all other lines from `b`. Based on the total number of lines and the number of lines between `a` and `b`, doing so could increase performance a lot compared to a two pass solution.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I think that's roughly equivalent to what I was proposing with dd, albeit using memory rather than seeking around on disk. :)

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM., I think the main concept you need to understand -- besides what others have already covered -- to grok why what you're asking for is impossible (unless the lengths of the lines match) is the limited semantics for in-place edits provided by POSIX filesystems. Bytes can be replaced in their position inside an existing file, but you can't make something longer or shorter without rewriting everything after it. And even then, awk doesn't provide access to the calls needed to do those kinds of edits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right , maybe I thought the awk language had an instruction to `goto` style ..... and that is impossible to read files sequentially

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM., the thing is that at a filesystem level, you can only seek to a certain number of **bytes** in, not a certain number of **lines** in. And to figure out how many bytes correspond with a certain number of lines, you need to read from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JoseRicardoBustosM. it is impossible to do it in one pass in awk without saving the lines from the init to one before the end line in memory. Just think about the impossibility of getting a line N lines ahead of what you've already read to miraculously show up in place of the current line. The best solution for this is definitely a simple 2-pass approach of saving the lines in the first pass and using them in the 2nd. I am including all solutions that involve grep-ing in advance or using a getline loop in the "2"-pass approach bucket.

FWIW here's the way I'd really do it (this IS a 2-pass approach):

```
$ cat swap_line.awk
BEGIN     { ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
NR==FNR   { if (NR==end) tl=$0; next }
FNR==init { hd=$0; $0=tl; nr=NR-FNR; if (nr<end) next }
FNR==end  { $0=hd }
FNR==nr   { if (nr<end) $0 = $0 ORS hd }
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -v init=2 -v end=4 -f swap_line.awk input
1
4
3
2
5

$ awk -v init=2 -v end=2 -f swap_line.awk input
1
2
3
4
5

$ awk -v init=2 -v end=8 -f swap_line.awk input
1
3
4
5
2
```

Note that if you didn't have that very specific requirement for how to handle an "end" that's past the end of the file then the solution would simply be:

```
$ cat swap_line.awk
BEGIN     { ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
NR==FNR   { if (NR==end) tl=$0; next }
FNR==init { hd=$0; $0=tl }
FNR==end  { $0=hd }
{ print }
```

and if you really want something to think about (again, just for the sunny day cases):

```
$ cat swap_line.awk
NR==init { hd=$0; while ((getline<FILENAME)>0 && ++c<end); }
NR==end  { $0=hd }
{ print }

$ awk -v init=2 -v end=4 -f swap_line.awk input
1
4
3
2
5
```

I would still consider that last one as a "2"-pass approach and I wouldn't do it if I didn't fully understand all the caveats listed at http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: As someone who doesn't do much awk (honestly, stumbled on this question because it was originally mistagged `bash`), I'm having a little trouble reading the logic here. Could you explain how this meets the spec (single-pass, no storage of content between the two lines to be swapped in-memory)?

Comment: this is also processing the file twice right? the trick is, you set the 2nd input file argument internally.   "cheater" ? ;-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as I said in my comment, it is not possible to do what the OP asked for. This is how I would actually do the task at hand. I'll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: @Kent yes, apparently, I have caused some confusion by not stating this is a 2-pass solution. I'll update my answer to state that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell in benchmark with file 10 millon of lines: (EdMorton 1): 5.870s (EdMorton 2): 4.126s and (WilliamPursell): 4.587s ..... even though your solution is efficient, I will select this answer, I think brings more to future readers ..... thanks a lot to both

Answer (score 2):

I think you are working too hard.  This makes no attempt to deal with extreme cases (eg, if end is greater than the number of lines, the initial line will not be printed, but that can easily be handled in an END block), because I think handling the edge cases obscures the idea.  Namely, print until you reach the line you want swapped out, then store data in a file, then print the line to swap, the stored data, and the initial line, and then print the rest of the file:

```
$ cat swap.sh
#!/bin/sh


trap 'rm -f $T1' 0
T1=$(mktemp)

awk '
        NR<init { print; next; }
        NR==init { f = $0; next; }
        NR<end { print > t1; next; }
        NR==end { print; system("cat "t1); print f; next; }
        1
' init=${1?} end=${2?} t1=$T1
$ yes | sed 10q | nl -ba | ./swap.sh 4 8
     1  y
     2  y
     3  y
     8  y
     5  y
     6  y
     7  y
     4  y
     9  y
    10  y
```

Comment: seems excessively complicated if you don't need to handle the "end past the end of file" requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that 2 passes are required. The first pass can be done with a tool(s) that is designed specifically for the task:

```
# $init and $end have been defined

endline=$( tail -n "+$end" file | head -n 1 )
awk -v init="$init" -v end="$end" -v endline="$endline" '
    NR == init {saved = $0; $0 = endline} 
    NR == end {$0 = saved} 
    {print}
' file
```

Hide the details away in a function:

```
swap_lines () { 
    awk -v init="$1" \
        -v end="$2" \
        -v endline="$(tail -n "+$2" "$3" | head -n 1)" \
    '
        NR == init {saved = $0; $0 = endline}
        NR == end {$0 = saved}
        1
    ' "$3"
}
seq 5 > file
swap_lines 2 4 file
1
4
3
2
5
```

Comment: benchmark (glennjackman): 2.493s ..... It works great .... I will continue to let EdMorton's response as it is 100% awk ..... thanks a lot

Comment: I thought about that too (but with `awk -v end="$end" 'NR==end{print; exit}' file` instead of the `tail ... | head ...` - idk which is faster) but then you still have to deal with the case where `end` is past the end of file and then per the example in the OPs question you can't print the `endline` as a replacement for the `init` line so you need some way to test for that and then you're back to a 2-pass approach since you can't just test `endline` is it could be NULL just due to the line at position `end` being empty rather than `end` being past `NR`.